# Issue with an Excel macro not copying data form 1 file to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel macro that is running correctly on over 10 pc's.
On 1 pc it does not run correctly.  It does not error out, just seems to not run to completion. All machines are running windows 10.
I have included the code below.
Fairly simple. Copies from "Follow_Up" sheet in the source file to "Sheet1" in the destination file.
It seems to stop just after it activates "Sheet1"

```
    Sub copydata1()
Dim wbSrc As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
Dim rngSrc As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set wbSrc = ActiveWorkbook
Sheets("Follow_Up").Activate


Workbooks.Open "G:\Estimating Templates\Bid List_Lee.xlsm"
Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
 -----seems to stop here---------

 Dim unusedRow As Long
unusedRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 0).Row



 j = ActiveCell.Row
j = unusedRow
  MsgBox j

wbSrc.Activate

 Sheets("Follow_Up").Select
  Range("L151").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CELL(""filename"")"
    Range("M151").Select

    Range("A151:Q151").Select
    Selection.Copy
   wbDest.Activate

    Sheet1.Cells(j, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheet1.Cells(j, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(j, 14)

            Sheet1.Cells(j, 17).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(RC[-1])"

      ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Range("A20").Select


    wbSrc.Activate
    Sheets("Follow_Up").Select
    Range("L151").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CELL(""filename"")"
    Range("M151").Select

     wbSrc.Activate
      Sheets("Summary").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably good to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and incorporate its points into your code.

Comment: To add to what @BigBen says, it is probably a waste of time to try to debug the code rather than rewriting it from the ground up without things like `.Activate` or `.Select`. That will probably solve the issue. The code is short, so rewriting it shouldn't take very long.

Comment: I agree with the previous comments, but I also have an idea: the newly opened workbook could not be activated so "sheet1" may not be available to activate. Set wbDest =Workbooks.Open (FileName:="G:\Estimating Templates\Bid List_Lee.xlsm")  then use  wdDest.activate. After it you can activate the sheet.

Comment: Where is the code located? In `wbSrc` or in a 3rd file?

Comment: The code is located in wbDest.

Comment: I'm talking about the code you have posted. It can be in `wbSrc`, a workbook containing `Sheet1` (CodeName) or another workbook. `wbDest` is definitely `Bid List_Lee.xlsm`

Comment: The code is in wbDest(Bid List_Lee.xlsm) It is run from  the excel tool bar. Each user has their own "Bid List"

Comment: Basically, the purpose of this is to copy data from  a "Follow_up" sheet in the workbook that the users have open, and copy it to their "Bid List" file. It is run by clicking an icon on the excel toolbar

Comment: The article took care of it!  Thank you all for your help.